# How to force mysql to return 0 for invalid id in IN array?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how to return `count(*) = 0` for the ids which don't exist?

source code:

```
SELECT hash, count(*) FROM myTable
WHERE hash IN (1111 /*available*/, 2222 /*not available*/)
GROUP BY hash
```

returns:

```
1111, 1
2222, 0
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get those `hash` values into rows somehow e.g.

```
select d.hash, count(t.hash)
from (
   select 1111 as hash union all
   select 2222
   ) d
left outer join myTable t on d.hash = t.hash
group by d.hash
```

The `left outer join` is important as it allows an unmatched value (such as 2222 in your example) to be listed in the results (with the count of 0).

`left outer join` may be abbreviated to `left join`

Comment: Thanks for your help, my main concern is how to handle it if there is a dynamic list of id's?

Comment: where does the list come from? (e.g. PHP?) It has to be done there I suspect. You may need another question about that.

Comment: The **best** way to get this is to have the list come from a `table` as opposed to an `IN ()` statement. That way, you can do `LEFT JOIN` and use `SUM(ISNULL(hash,0,1))`. Easy in a `STORED PROCEDURE` With a temp table.